# Gradle Build Failure for JasperReports: Dependency Issue

Tags: gradle, itext, jasper-reports

My build.gradle is as follows:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports
compile group: 'net.sf.jasperreports', name: 'jasperreports', version: '6.9.0'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lowagie/itext
compile group: 'com.lowagie', name: 'itext', version: '2.1.7.js6'

repositories {
maven {
    url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone'
}
 maven {
    url 'http://maven.icm.edu.pl/artifactory/repo/'
}
```

The error I am getting is as follows.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all files for configuration ':Services:compileClasspath'.

  > Could not find com.lowagie:itext:2.1.7.js6.
  >   Required by:
  >     project :Services
  >     project :Services > net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:6.9.0

Reference link: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lowagie/itext/2.1.7.js6

What is going wrong here? Please help.

Comment: Can you find that artifact on Maven Central, search.maven.org, with that exact version? That is the official central Maven repository which is also used by Gradle. Mvnrepository.com is nothing more than a mirror/search engine. If the artifact can't be found on Maven Central, then this error is expected. You may need to *explicitly* add mvnrepository.com as one of your repositories. If that indeed solves it, post back, and then I'll rewrite my comment into an answer so you can accept it.

Comment: Use item 3 of the accepted answer of the linked question.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse it is present in mvnrepository.com but not in Maven Central. Could you help with the Gradle changes please.

Comment: I cannot help you with the Gradle changes. I don't know anything about Gradle, I have never before in my life used it. I'm convinced that you know more about Gradle than I do.

Answer (score 7):

Adding these to the repositories fixed the issue for me

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven{url "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/maven2/"}
    maven{url "http://jaspersoft.artifactoryonline.com/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/"
}
}
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:6.1.0'
    ...
}
```

Comment: Please use the secure https path: https://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

//jdk-11

repositories {

```
mavenCentral()
...
maven{url "https://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/ui/native/jaspersoft-repo"}

maven {url "https://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts"}
...
```

}

dependencies {

```
...
implementation 'net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:6.20.0'

implementation 'com.lowagie:itext:2.1.7.js10'
...
```

}

source: https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/1210036/gradle-jasperreports-dependency-fails-resolve

Answer (score 0):

**Java 17 Spring boot Gradle Kotlin - worked for me below**

```
implementation("net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:6.20.0"){
 exclude(group="com.lowagie", module= "itext")}
```